# Best way to open URL in Android

Tags: android

Wondering if anyone knows the most optimized way to handle opening an URL in android.  Here is how I am doing it:

```
String tempUrl = helper.getUrl(tempString);
            Intent i = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW", Uri.parse("http://"+tempUrl));
            startActivity(i);
```

Must you start a new activity in order to open a URL?

Answer (score 3):

I think you are using the correct way

```
 Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://"+tempUrl));
 startActivity(i);
```

other way would be loading your URL into a WebView.

```
myWebView.loadUrl(http://"+tempUrl);
```

this is a basic example:

```
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://stackoverflow.com/"));
startActivity(browserIntent);
```

Comment: Remember to add a try/catch if the url is not http you might get an exception here.